# Webspeed integration for insterting and consulting data from my progress database

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl, progress-db, webspeed

I'm working in this new company, and they are using ARM with progress Databases. I'm trying to make a webapp where I can insert data on the Progress DB and also select and show data from this DB. 
I tried some PhP, but then I learned that PhP does not work with Progress. I have never used Webspeed or even Progress.

Answer (score 1):

Progress' documentation can be found here:

https://community.progress.com/community_groups/openedge_general/w/openedgegeneral/1329.openedge-product-documentation-overview

And the knowledgebase is here:

https://knowledgebase.progress.com/pkb_Home

There are also community forums that are pretty good for unstructured q&a conversations at:

https://community.progress.com/community_groups/openedge_development/f/19

or if you prefer vendor independent sources:

https://www.progresstalk.com/

and

https://openedge.slack.com

If you have a specific question that fits the stackoverflow model it is helpful to use tags like "openedge", "progress-db", "progress-4gl", and "webspeed".  Plain old "progress" gets you lumped in with a questions that are mostly about "progress bars" and such.